# base64 decoded image error when opening, NodeJS

Tags: string, image, base64, decode

I am receiving string base64 encoded, when I try to decode and save in to an image file, it seems to be everything working fine, but when I download open the file, my viewer does not recognize it. 
I know my string is a valid image because I use http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html
and it sends me the right image. 
Is there something I am missing?

```
    var imagestring = "/9j/2wCEAA0JCQsJCA0LCgsODQ0PEx8UExEREyYbHRcfLSgwLy0oLCsyOEg9MjVENissP1U/REpNUFFQMDxYX1hOXkhPUE0BDQ4OExATJRQUJU00LDRNTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTU1NTf/AABEIAHgAoAMBIQACEQEDEQH/3QAEAAr/xAGiAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+gEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoLEQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4Q=hYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDzcU6gBamtztlVj0BzTA2rK5njm3xHaCMdamuNUvktHLT7HzxwOlaNX1HYt2mpS3cCOyrkjn61Zhjyc4rCTuCL0aYFThayKFxTSKoQhFNIq0AhFNNUA0nnFIatEjaKoD//0POBS0AKK1vD1it/fNFIPl8tvwPQH8yKqKuxPYtDFudkjhCDg57Gs+5DzT4RzLn05q5PSxTN7TLYwWqKwO7GSPetWFK5ZAi2i1IBUIYYppFUAhFNIq0A00w1YhpppqkIaaSrQH//0fNw6+tHmL60AKJE9a6Hwtq+naW8811JiUgBBtJHv0H0pp2Ey5JrGiTytLcSI7tyS0TH+lRnW9KUlYZlRPRYmA/lSdnsMlj13TF63P8A443+FW4/EWkjrd/+Q3/wrJpjROviXSB/y9/+Q3/wp3/CTaP/AM/f/kN/8KmzHcT/AISbSP8An7/8hv8A4U3/AISXSP8An7/8hv8A4VVguIfEuk/8/f8A5Df/AApD4k0n/n7/APIb/wCFUFxp8R6V/wA/X/kN/wDCmHxFpf8Az9f+Q2/wqhDT4h0v/n6/8ht/hTf+Eg0z/n4=f/Ibf4VSYhDr+mf8/P8A443+FJ/b+m/8/P8A443+FUmgP//S8xooAKeikg4GaAEpQKAFPXijJpNAKHKkZORU2KlgJRSASimAlFMBKKoAooA//9PzGigAqxb8L9aaEyN12OR27UgPpSGPFPCA+30qW7ACwqDk80/FTe4CUUAJSUwCkqgA0lABRTA//9TzGigAqePOAAKaAWVcgEjkVGCKT0AehBrodM8Nf2lpMl9HqVhGY87oZZtr4Hes5XAq3ei31iqtc2skaOMo+Mqw9mHB/A1RZCp5qUAwimmqQCUlMAopgIaSmAUUwP/V8xooAUDJxU8W4nk8U0JhM2DwagAzQ9xomVRjFSpKE+XNS0B6h8ONZN9p0ulTyxyGLmOGUfeTuAfb6HrXNeP4LO11wwWdiLQog8xVI2sTzkAHAGMen0qOgHKq/wA5UjpSHrQA2imAlFMBKSmAUUwP/9bzGigBynByKnB2jLZPsKaEQuxdqcq0hjxwMYqJvlNAFi0neOTcjFSvIIOMGrl7qFxqEomu5Wmk2hd7dSB0ye59zWb3AqYAORSUAFIaYCUUwEpKYBRTA//X8xooAkQY579qepOeRTQh/lq3I+U0vlNjjB+hp2C5XO4mgRsfQVFxk6KEGBTs1ABmkpgFJQAUlUAlFMBKWgD/0PMaXtQA4NgU8HPamBI=opxUihgeRxVElXvTxWJQ6lpAFFMBKKAEoqgCkpgFFAH/0fMhS4zQA5Bg89KsrFVJXEyVI8U8lY1LN0Fa2sSZobJzUi1yssdS0AFFABRTQBSUwCimAUlAH//S8xHWpAD6UALkVaicGMEnpxVR3ExXuAmODzURD3b7UWRyOdqDNOcugkQlAhwev1pVPNZFD6WkAUUAFFMAopgFJTAKKAP/0/MgcUu8kYzQAnSpI5CnB6UICdgJE4AJ6iozdzmEwCVliJyY1OFJ9SB1NE1cRFThUjHA04UgCloAKKoAopgFFABRQB//1PNNnHPFIv3hkcUAObaBxTaAJoG8sknOKY4yxI4BND2ENxTqkYopc0AOzRQAUUwClpgFFABRQB//1fNnBAzTBuHQUkA7BI5HIpQCDkDFCAX5j2pdrelAFmx0y51CUx26AsBnk4qOW0kgcpIMMpwajmV7CIzGR2pNp9KoYoU+lLtPpQAu0+lG0+lMA2n0pdp9KYBtPpRtPpQAbT6UFTQB/9k=";
var decodedImage = new Buffer(imagestring, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('imagedecoded.jpg', decodedImage , function(err) {});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `fs.writeFile('imagedecoded.jpg, decodedImage)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, and thanks for the advice, I updated the question. But Still with the same issue. When openning the file it shows an error. But I know it is a valid Image because with the freeformatter online, I can decode it succesfully.

Comment: I think the base64 string is not a valid image. `http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter` you can use this to test your base64 encoded string.

Comment: But why with this converter works fine?
http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html